# Consider a right - angled triangle ABC where AB = AC = 3. A rectangle APOQ is drawn inside it,

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

I have tried a lot but could not able to solve it

Comment: Similarity. $AB$ is $15$ times as long as $OS$. So $\triangle ABC$ has area $15^2$ times the area of $\triangle OST$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
Area of $\Delta ~ABC=\cfrac{1}{2}\times \text{base}\times \text{hight}=\cfrac{1}{2}\times 3\times 3=4.5$

$\because~AB=AC \implies \angle ACB=\angle ABC$

$\because QS~||~AB\implies \angle QOC=\angle SOT $

$\because AC~||~ST\implies\angle ACB=\angle BTM=\angle OTS$

$\therefore \angle SOT =\angle OTS\implies OS=ST$

And it is given that $OS=0.2$

Therefore area of $\Delta OST =\cfrac{1}{2}\times 0.2\times 0.2=0.02$

Hence $\cfrac{\text{Area of} ~\Delta ABC}{\text{Area of} ~\Delta OST}=\cfrac{4.5}{0.02}=225$

Comment: \cdot and \text{} might come in handy

Comment: Yeah !  I agree with you